Class \"Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\Facade\" not found"
on localhost this package works fine but when I deploy it on live server and I tried to generate pdf I got this error
Class \"Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\Facade\" not found"

what was the reason behind this my code is
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

I got error on this line of code
        $pdf = Pdf::loadHTML($htmlContent);

my config/app.php code is
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
  Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
 ])->toArray(),
 'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'Example' => App\Facades\Example::class,
        'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
   ])->toArray(),

and on both localhost and live server have php version 8.2

The class you're looking for is Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf.
Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
    'PDF' => \Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::class,
])->toArray(),

use PDF;

$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($htmlContent);


Although you don't really need to create an alias, using the default facade is perfectly fine.
Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
    // nothing
])->toArray(),

use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;

$pdf = Pdf::loadHTML($htmlContent);

Remember that Pdf and PDF can be 2 different things depending on your system.

I have the same problem like this Class "Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\PDF" not found but without putting any code on the config/app.php. It works before on local tho here's my code use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\PDF; $pdf = PDF::loadView($data)

Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\PDF does not exist.  You're looking for Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf. Your local environment is probably windows or mac (case-insensitive).

yes that is the answer, thankyou very much. if u want, u can answer to my question here for some reputations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78700936/class-barryvdh-dompdf-facade-pdf-not-found-in-laravel-11-when-deploying-live?noredirect=1#comment138763123_78700936

You're welcome, but in the spirit of not giving duplicate answers, I'll just link to this question
